# converting confidence interval to a different percentage

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

We are given a 95% confidence interval with some range - in this particular case (4.0; 11.0) - and asked to find the 90% and 99% confidence intervals for the same parameter, assuming normal distribution, without any aditional information.

I am not sure how to solve this: interval = $\bar x \pm (t)(s_\bar x)$
So even if I am to get the new t-value based on the new percentage, I wouldn't know how to calculate the new intervals, since it's only multiplied by the standard error.. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: The ratio of lengths of intervals does not depend on standard error.

Comment: The normal distribution is symmetric about the mean

Comment: Are you given a z or a t confidence interval. If t, do you know the sample size $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your formulae $\bar{x} \pm t \times s_{\bar{x}}$, it seems like you are dealing with a $t$ confidence interval. If so, you will need the sample size $n$ to accurately get the 90% or 99% confidence interval.

But, just to clarify the thought process, suppose the 95% confidence interval given $(4, 11)$ is a $z$ confidence interval. If so, you can get the other confidence intervals based on the following logic (some of which also apply in the $t$ confidence interval scenario as well).

First, the mid-point of that interval is the sample mean $\bar{x}$ by design. So $\bar{x} = (4+11)/2 = 7.5$.

Second, the half-length of the interval is $1.96 \times \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$.

So $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}  = \frac{(11-7.5)}{1.96}= \frac{3.5}{1.96}$.

Then, 90% confidence interval:

$$\bar{x} \pm 1.645 \times \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} \quad \Rightarrow  \quad 7.5 \pm 1.645 \times \frac{3.5}{1.96} $$

Comment: Yes that must be it - I must have used the wrong formula, and it should be a z-interval